# classical topology but with lattices

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lattice-orders

I'm looking for a reference, if such a references exists.

So there are currently at least two approaches to topology.

1. The point-set or "classical" approach to topology, which concerns itself with ordered pairs $(X,\tau)$ called *topological spaces*.
2. The "pointless" approach to topology, which concerns itself with (particular kinds of) lattices $(\tau,\wedge,\vee)$ called *frames*. (For more information, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology).)

I'm interested in a concept halfway between 1 and 2. We might call it "the classical approach, but with lattices."

In particular, rather than studying point-set topological spaces $(X,\tau)$, we concern ourselves with "lattice-theoretic" topological spaces $(P,\tau)$, where $P$ is a lattice that is isomorphic to a powerset lattice, and $\tau$ is a subset of $P$ that is closed with respect to arbitrary joins etc.

The main motivation: We may be able to weaken the requirement that $P$ needs to be isomorphic to a powerset, and thereby obtain a more general theory, which is still classical in flavor.

Has this idea been studied before? If so, a reference recommendation would be great.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on how what you are looking for is different to locale theory? The only way I can interpret the above is that $\tau$ is a subset of P that is closed under arbitrary joins and finite meets. Weakening P from being a powerset lattice to just a complete lattice gives you locales precisely. So, unless you have some special subclass of lattices in mind, your question is not precise enough.

Comment: @IttayWeiss You write, "The only way I can interpret the above is that $\tau$ is a subset of $P$ that is closed under arbitrary joins and finite meets." Yes this is precisely what I mean. This is different from a locale, which makes no mention of $P$ whatsoever.

Comment: ahhh, I see what you mean. Is the following the definition you have in mind: Suppose you have some functor F:Set-->CLat. Say that an F-topological space is a pair $(X,\tau)$ such that $X$ is a set and $\tau$ is a subset of $F(X)$, closed under arbitrary unions and finite meets. The case F(x)=powerset of X gives precisely ordinary topological spaces.

Comment: To be honest, all that categorical stuff kind of defeats me... All I was thinking is that if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, then $\mathcal{P}X$ can be viewed as a lattice, so $(\mathcal{P}X,\tau)$ can be viewed as a "lattice-theoretic" topological space. Furthermore, we can forget about the fact that $\mathcal{P}X$ and $\tau$ are collections of sets. Who cares what they're collections of! What matters is how they relate. This is kind of like - who cares what the elements of a group are. Whether they're functions or matrices or whatever, doesn't matter. What matters is how they relate.

Comment: However, it's possible that what you're saying is more interesting than what I'm saying.

Comment: I don't know of any relevant references. It is an interesting exercise to see how far you can develop topology using lattice theory only. Good question!

Comment: But what is there to relate $\tau$ to $P$? As far as I can tell, $P$ is just some arbitrary lattice in which you can embed the frames/locales $(\tau,\wedge,\vee)$. This embedding cannot be unique (you can always add additional points to $P$ that is not in $\tau$ almost arbitrarily). Hence I don't expect that more can be said about $P$ then what can be said about $\tau$ in the theory of locales or frames.

Comment: We require that $\tau$ be closed with respect to finite meets, for example. What does "meet" mean? The notion of meet comes from $P$, not $\tau$. Whereas in the theory of locales, the notion of meet comes from $\tau$.

Comment: But $\tau$ is surely by definition a sublattice of $P$. How will you differentiate between, say, $(P,\tau)$ and $(P\cup \{\infty\},\tau)$ where $\infty \wedge p = \infty$ and $\infty \vee p = p$ for every $p\in P$?

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. The "lattice-theoretic topological spaces" $(P,\tau)$ and $(P \cup \{\infty\},\tau)$ are different spaces. The notions of meet and join are different in these spaces. So even if $\tau$ is closed with respect to finite meets and arbitrary joins when the meanings of "meet" and "join" come from $P$, it needn't be closed in this way when the meanings of "meet" and "join" come from $P\cup\{\infty\}$. But, is this a problem?

Comment: By the definition I gave, the two will coincide. One can talk about whether it is worthwhile to carry extra useless baggage (things like $P\neq Q$ as lattices but their topologies $\tau = \sigma$ are isomorphic as lattices; of course, from the categorical point of view it seems that the indiscrete topology is useful, so I won't argue this point too far). But mainly I wanted to point out that perhaps your natural generalisation would require $P$ to be a bounded lattice and that $\tau$ contains $\sup P$ and $\inf P$ both, since those facts have generally been useful in topology.

Comment: Well if $P$ is isomorphic to a powerset, it will certainly be bounded. And if $\tau$ is closed with respect to finite meets and arbitrary joins, it will be closed with respect the empty meet and empty join.

Comment: Oh i see what youre saying. Yes, i agree.

Comment: If you demand that your frame $\tau$ is embedded as a subframe of $P X$ for some set $X$, then you are asserting that $\tau$ actually is a topology on $X$. In effect, you are suggesting that we restrict the study of locales to those that actually come from topological spaces. In other words there is no added generality at all! So why not just study these things _qua_ topological spaces?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, I'm just after a reference. You're right that unless the requirement that $P$ be isomorphic to a powerset is weakened, the concept is no more general than that of a classical topological space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a precise reference. But this may give you something to look at and/or some people to ask.

If you had asked me the similar question about *convexity* instead of *topology*, I would've given you a positive answer. The classical point-set topology satisfies the following axioms on the topology of closed sets $\tau \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$:

1. $\tau \ni {\emptyset, X}$
2. for any finite subset $K\subseteq\tau$ we have $\cup K\in \tau$
3. for any subset $J \subseteq \tau$ we have $\cap J \in \tau$.

The collection of all convex subsets $C$ on an affine space $E$ satisfy a similar collection of properties:

1. $C \ni {\emptyset, X}$
2. for any subset $J \subseteq C$ we have $\cap J \in C$
3. (optional, depending on definition) for any directed (with respect to inclusion) subset $S\subseteq C$ we have $\cup S \in C$

So one sees that there are certain similarities between convex structures and topological structures.

Now, for convex structures, something like what you proposed *has been developed*. It is sometimes called "abstract convexity", and one formulation is something like this:

> **Defn**: Let $(X,\leq)$ be a complete lattice. A *convexity system* $\mathcal{C} \subseteq X$ is a subset that is closed under infimum. The system is said to be *inductive* if it is in addition closed under directed supremums.

Note that $X$ does not have to be the powerset lattice for a set. It turns out that many facts of convex analysis can be reproduced in this more general context.  See, for example, Ivan Singer's *Abstract Convex Analysis* or MLJ van der Vel's *Theory of Convex Structures*.

Given the similarity between convex structures and topological ones (for example, the convex hull operator is almost a closure operator in the Kuratowski sense), maybe the sort of "topology as a subset of a complete lattice" point of view can be found linked to from the literature in abstract convexity, and maybe the experts in that area can point you in the right direction so-to-speak.

Comment: Cool I'll check it out. I've actually encountered this concept before, except defined in the less general "point-set" fashion (rather than a "lattice-theoretic" fashion). It goes under the name "aligned space," in Coppel's [Foundations of Convex Geometry](http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Geometry-Australian-Mathematical-Society/dp/0521639700).

Comment: Also, I think a few of your definitions are slightly off. Like 1 should feature a superset symbol, not an ownership symbol.

Comment: @user18921 corrected. I was changing between two sets of notations and evidently didn't make everything line up. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Also, and this is a technicality that EVERYONE get wrong, not just you, the collection of all closed sets in a topological space is not really closed under arbitrary intersections. In particular, the empty intersection gives the wrong answer - you wind up getting the universal class, rather than $X$. A little nicety of the lattice-theoretic approach is that this is automatically dealt with.

Comment: To put that less strongly, it's perhaps not "wrong," but at least in need of a mention. Taking a lattice theoretic approach, it's simply true without qualification. Also, let me just point out that $\tau \ni \emptyset$ (or, more precisely, $\tau \ni \bot$) is implied by closure with respect to joins, and $\tau \ni X$ (or, more precisely, $\tau \ni \top$) is implied by closure with respect to meets.

Comment: @user18921 that is more a matter of convention and brevity, which I am well aware of. For example in the more formal definition of the convexity system which I gave the membership requirement is conveniently omitted.

Comment: Certainly mention of $\tau \ni \emptyset$ and $\tau \ni X$ is a matter of convention. As for the "fluid" definition of empty intersection, I think it's rather problematic. For instance, if we're dealing with two topological spaces at the same time, with different underlying sets $X$ and $Y$, should we choose $\bigcap \emptyset = X$, or should we choose $\bigcap \emptyset = Y$? It's a little messy either way.

Comment: @user18921 What I meant is, one could say: "$X\in \tau$" and "closed under arbitrary nonempty intersections", or one could be more verbose and define closure under intersections to be "$\cap (K\cup\{X\}) \in \tau$". Everybody _knows_ that this is what is meant, and unless one actually works in foundations relatively little harm can come from an abuse of notation. I mean, next you will complain that $A^c$ is a bad notation for $X\setminus A$ because the set $X$ is not explicitly mentioned in $A$ (or for a less trivial example $S^\perp$ where $S\subseteq V$ an inner product space)....

Comment: Ha! Fair enough. I wan't really trying to say that anything is bad notation for anything else. I guess was trying to say: the definitions are SLIGHTLY asymmetric. When you ask yourself WHY??? you inevitably come to the conclusion that it's because you're using a powerset to "model" a lattice. The powerset is a means; the lattice is the end. Sorry, I wasn't trying to be insolent or argumentative or anything.

Comment: Ah, do you mean asymmetric as in the closed-set definition versus the open-set ones? Then I think I see better what you are getting at. Though I am not sure if one should blame the point-set formulation of topology, or the fact that foundations take the point of view that everything is a set.... In any case, I am relatively not interested in getting into foundational discussions. So this will probably be my last comment on the issue.

Comment: I think we're talking about the same thing. In the open-set definition of a topological space, we define that arbitrary unions of open sets are open. In the closed-set definition, we define that finite unions of closed sets are closed. But once we start talking about intersections, we're forever using the "non-empty" qualification. Coming at it from another angle, the meaning of "union" is consistent across contexts, whereas the meaning of "intersection" is slightly fluid, or as you put it, we really mean $\cap(K \cup\{X\})$. That's the asymmetry.

Comment: Yes I don't want to get into a foundational discussion either. Anyway, I appreciate your time.